# currency field and currency switch with currency module

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I installed the [Currency module](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency) expecting to setup a currency field and a currency switch. Like switching the language, I'd like to switch the currency (of a field). The currency should switch depending on localization path or the set currency in a currency switch.

I have no idea how to set a field as a currency field and how to get a currency switch.

Is this possible with Currency? If yes, how?