# How to add currency field?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

With respect to the [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145602/currency-field-and-currency-switch-with-currency-module), can anyone suggest a remedy for the same. 
How can I create a field for currency(with selecting currency and text field to enter the amount) considering the fact that there are multiple currencies.

I have tried adding prefix but it can input only a single value(for example $ or pound etc). I have also tried the currency module but it gives a single page with multiple currencies.

Answer (score 0):

So to add a decimal field.

- edit your content type.
- manage fields
- add new field
- select Decimal from the Field Type dropdown, click the 'Save' button
- Change 'Scale' to 2. These are the cents, 'Save field settings' button.
- In the Prefix field add '$' and save settings.

[image]

Comment: But how to manipulate if there are more than one currency.? Eg $, AED, INR etc

Comment: you try currency module : https://www.drupal.org/project/currency

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't help my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should install module 'currency', add a field of type Entity reference, and choose the 'currency' as the referred type.